# BigInteger partitioned into parts

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to access certain parts of a big integer. In particular, I want to divide the big integer into 4 equal parts. If the bit length is not divisible by 4, I want enough leading zeros added to make the length a multiple of 4. I have the following code that works as described:

```
public static BigInteger[] partition(BigInteger a) {
    int base = (a.bitLength()+3)/4;

    BigInteger upper = a.shiftRight(2*base);
    BigInteger lower = a.subtract(upper.shiftLeft(2*base));
    BigInteger a2 = lower.shiftRight(base);
    BigInteger a1 = lower.subtract(a2.shiftLeft(base));
    BigInteger a4 = upper.shiftRight(base);
    BigInteger a3 = upper.subtract(a4.shiftLeft(base));
    return new BigInteger[] {a1, a2, a3, a4};
}
```

The problem with this code is the overhead of creating many additional  big integers as well as many unnecessary shifts and subtracts. Perhaps a test can be added to make sure that `a` has at least 4 bits, but that is not necessary in my case since I know that to be true before calling the function.

Is there a way to extend the BigInteger class and work with the `int[] mag` array directly? The extended class should have something similar to `partition` given above where it returns an array of 4 immutable BigInteger values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not quite get your problem in fact.  Wish what I am answering make sense to you :) .

In `BigInteger` it does provide `toByteArray()` which returns a `byte[]` containing the 2-compliment representation of the `BigInteger` itself.  On the same time there is a constructor taking `byte[]`.

Therefore your solution can be as easy as getting the byte array, partition the byte array by whatever dirty way you want, and create each result BigInteger accordingly.  This should save you from creating lots unnecessary `BigInteger`s as what you are concerning.

Comment: The problem with what you say is the same as the code I posted. The byte array is a copy of the underlying `int[] mag` array beause the class is immutable. Is there a way to skip this additional copy operation and directly work with the underlying `int[] mag` array.

Comment: I think at least it save several temp objects as in your original code.  Designed as a immutable object, working against the underlying `int[]` of the result BigInteger may not be that preferable.  I'd rather reuse the temporary `byte[]` during your arithmetic, which further save temp obj (temp objs involved are the byte array returned from the original BigInteger, and the temp byte array you use for arithmetic for each result BigInteger)

Comment: After thinking long and hard about it, I've decided what I really need is a mutable big integer class. Given the limitations of the standard library, I agree with you that what you propose is likely the only reasonable solution. Since the boundary may fall in the middle of a byte, the implementation is not trivial and I may post my code. For now, I accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: imho, the not-in-byte-boundary is not something hard to solve.  My biggest concern on your work is more about negative number.  Are you going to have 2-complient representation for negative number?  And, your splitting logic is going to cause ambiguous result, for example: 1010101 and 1111 are going to give you same result.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: No, no negative numbers. There is also no ambiguity. It is true that leading zeros in the three lower partitions disappear. But that is not a problem since the base is fixed. It is implied, but fixed.

Comment: I don't quite get why there is no ambiguity :P  just use my example, both (binary) `1010101` and `1111` are giving you 4 `BigInteger`s with value 1.  How can you distinguish between them?

Comment: In your example, 1010101 has a base of 2, while 1111 has a base of 1. Knowing the base, the original number can be reproduced. The base is not returned as part of the result, but is associated with it. The mathematical base is 2^2 and 2^1, respectively. But I think that is clear :)

Comment: Before you ask, the reason the base is not returned is that it is always of the form $2^n$ where $n$ is a regular integer. In theory, it can be returned as the fifth element of the big integer array, or as part of a class tailored for that. It is just simpler to return the result and assume the caller didn't forget about the base, which renders the result useless.